# calculate wspace in gridspec with specified width ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to calculate `wspace` for custom adjustment of subplots specified by `gridspec` to, for example, put text between two subplots without overlapping with axes. According to [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html), `wspace` is

> the amount of width reserved for space between subplots, expressed as a fraction of the average axis width.

So it can be calculated by `(ax1_pos.x0 - ax0_pos.x1) / (ax1_pos.x1 - ax1_pos.x0)`, as was pointed out [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6939/).
However, when I applied `width_ratios` parameters in `gridspec`, the `wspace` calculated becomes not consistent with the assigned `wspace`, and seems proportional to the ratio. Any clue about the adjustment of  `wspace` by `width_ratios`?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=30, wspace=0.5)
gs1_pos = gs[:, 1].get_position(fig)
gs0_pos = gs[:, 0].get_position(fig)
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 1])
print("Grids 0 position")
print(gs0_pos)
print("Grids 1 position")
print(gs1_pos)
print('space between figures represented as a fraction of axis width')
print((gs1_pos.x0 - gs0_pos.x1) / (gs1_pos.x1 - gs1_pos.x0))
# return 0.5
```

But once applying `width_ratio`, then

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=30, width_ratios=[1, 4], wspace=0.5)
gs1_pos = gs[:, 1].get_position(fig)
gs0_pos = gs[:, 0].get_position(fig)
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 1])
print("Grids 0 position")
print(gs0_pos)
print("Grids 1 position")
print(gs1_pos)
print('space between figures represented as a fraction of axis width')
print((gs1_pos.x0 - gs0_pos.x1) / (gs1_pos.x1 - gs1_pos.x0))
# return 0.3125
```

Answer (score 0):

Though still don't get the point how `matplotlib` calculates `wspace` in my case, there exists a factor proportional to the ratio set, so that the correction can be achieved. I found the factor for different ratios are

> f = 1 for 1:1
>
> f = 0.75 for 1:2
>
> f = 2/3 for 1:3
>
> f = 0.625 for 1:4
>
> ......

These factors can be obtained by setting `wspace` to `0.1`.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
for r in range(1, 10):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=30, width_ratios=[1, r])
    gs.update(wspace=0.1)
    gs1_pos = gs[:, 1].get_position(fig)
    gs0_pos = gs[:, 0].get_position(fig)
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 1])
    print('space between figures represented as a fraction of axis width')
    print(round((gs1_pos.x0 - gs0_pos.x1) / (gs1_pos.x1 - gs1_pos.x0) * 10, 4))
```

Then correct the fraction to get the set `wspace` by dividing the factor

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
# factors for ratios 1 to 9
factors = [1, 0.75, 0.667, 0.625, 0.6, 0.583, 0.571, 0.562, 0.556]
for r in range(1, 10):
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=30, width_ratios=[1, r], wspace=0.6)
    gs1_pos = gs[:, 1].get_position(fig)
    gs0_pos = gs[:, 0].get_position(fig)
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 0])
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:, 1])
    print(round((gs1_pos.x0 - gs0_pos.x1) / (gs1_pos.x1 - gs1_pos.x0) / factors[r-1], 4))
```

Gets

```
0.6, 0.6, 0.5997, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6003, 0.6005, 0.6005, 0.5995
```